# licensing Intellilock w/ SmartAssembly

Tags: c#, encryption, licensing, obfuscation, intellilock

I am trying to wrap IntelliLock licensing over an exe that was run through Smart Assembly encryption & obfuscation.  When I do, it creates a locked file that runs the licensing code but will not spawn the application it wraps.  I tested other licensing systems like ElecKey and PC Guard and most of them don't work, PC Guard actually does work so I know it is possible.

Any idea of anything that can be to make this work?

I've successfully used all the licensing systems with .exe outputted from C# but this is a proprietary system that outputs .net exe's run through smartassembly first.

Comment: can you show+tweak the smartassembly settings ?

Comment: No, they are set by the proprietary system that outputs the exe.

Comment: then there is no way to help... you need to contact the support of the licensing system and give them the EXE so they can try and find a way to make that work...

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at **CryptoLicensing** + **Crypto Obfuscator** as mentioned in my answer to your other question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043550/licensing-net-assemblies/8075080#8075080